# Visual Studio Project that execute an SQL script

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have this question... probably is similar to [Executing scripts from a database project in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220705/executing-scripts-from-a-database-project-in-visual-studio)

but i didn't understand the solution given.

So i made a Database Server 2008 project inside visual studio.
Just one table. When i press DEPLOY the database is created inside SQLServer2008 and the table is created.

Now what if i would like to give the project to someone who has SQLServer and he needs to recreate the database and the table in his computer?.. 
Apart form executing the query from Visual Studio is there any way to create an executable that automatically "deploy" from outside Visual Studio?..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of Database projects in Visual Studio. The old ones, which were not so feature rich. The 'Data Dude' ones that came with Visual Studio 2010 Team Database Edition and the most recent iteration that comes with the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx). All of these can be installed on top of the standard Visual Studio Professional and don't require additional licenses.

SQL Server Data Tools is the latest, and also the best integrated and most powerful variant of the bunch. It can also be used to compare existing schema's and generate upgrade scripts or automatically upgrade the schema in an existing database for you.

During build, a package will be created that holds all the schema information for your database. You can then use the [command line tools provided by the SQL Server data tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371879/deploy-sql-server-2012-db-project-via-command-line-sql-server-data-tools-ctp4) or [MSDeploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550081%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to deploy your compressed schema file to a new or an existing database.

This deployment mechanism can also upgrade existing schema if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I'm still trying to understand how to make it works...

Comment: @Ivan_nn2 - did you get this working? I would second jessehouwing hunch that you're not using the most appropriate (latest) database project type.